# How do I create a VirtualDisk that spans two drives without redundancy using Power Shell

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces

This is my first time in many years where I've used Windows Server.  I was encouraged to set up Windows Server 2016 and assumed it had a GUI.

To my surprise this version has no desktop experience.  I believe it's called "Core".

I have the OS installed on an SSD and 2 12TB hard disks attached that I want to make available as a single Virtual Disk.

How do I do that with PowerShell?  I've gotten as far as creating a Pool which I've called "StoragePool1" which uses both disks.  But now I'm stuck on the VirtualDisk step.  It came up with an error when I ran a regular New-VirtualDisk command with a size of 21TB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, which may be useful for others.

The key was to add the setting `-ResiliencySettingName Simple` to the New-VirtualDisk command
.

For example, the following will use the entire space available across both drives.  There is no resiliency here.  Any drive loss will result in data loss.
For my specific purpose this is more than acceptable.

```
New-VirtualDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName StoragePool1 -FriendlyName VirtualDisk1 -ResiliencySettingName Simple -UseMaxiumSize
```